# How to protect to access unauthenticated static page in next js directly through url?

Tags: next.js, next-router

I want to navigate to a Page only through button click on some other page and not through typing direct url route in browser in Next JS. Page is static and unauthenticated.

Comment: so you want to allow only authenticated users to navigate to the page and restrict unauthorised users from directly typing the url . Is that correct?

Comment: authenticated or unauthenticated i want them not to be able to access page through url but only through clicking button on some other page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve this , you have to use `getServerSideProps`. In `getServerSideProps` a `request` object is passed on every request. In the `request` object `referer`  header is available which contains address of the page making the request.

**Note** that `referer` header in only available when user comes to specific page through a link. The header  is not availabe when url is directly typed in search bar.

You can do something like this:

```
export async function getServerSideProps ({ params , req  }) {
  const post = await githubCms.getPost(params.slug)  
  const referer  =  req.headers.referer || null
  


  return {
    props: {
      post , referer
    }
  }
}
```

Now you can pass `referer` prop to your component and can change your rendering logic.

**Important**: Note that when you refreshes your page the referer becomes null . So you need to check if someone refreshes the page logic  or you have to store the referer in local storage